# Helm: Datadog Agent with JDBC driver

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, datadog

I would like to use the [Datadog Oracle Integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/oracle/) via the [Helm Chart Datadog](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/datadog). Oracle Integration states *To use the Oracle integration, either install the Oracle Instant Client libraries, or download the Oracle JDBC Driver.*

I do not want to use a custom image to package the JDBC-driver, I want to use a standard image such as tag:7-jmx. Other options that come to mind (e.g. EFS volume with the driver inside) seem to be an overkill also.

Best option to me seems to be an init container that downloads the JDBC driver. But Datadog Helm Chart does not support custom init containers for the agents.

What's the best way to do this? To get an Datadog Agent with a JDBC driver via Helm?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Datadog Support to this:

> Thanks again for reaching out to Datadog!
>
> From looking further into this, there does not seem to be a way we can package the JDBC  driver with the Datadog Agent. I understand that this is not desirable as you would prefer to use a standard image but I believe the best way to have these bundled together would be to have a custom image for your deployment.
>
> Apologies for any inconveniences that this may cause.